# Sample size for tracking data

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, sample-size

I'm currently trying to figure out how to estimate a fitting sample size for a specific problem. The situation is as follows: We've got x people, of whom we are able to track y% - all the time, so we know where they are at any given time. Our subjects are free to move as they wish (inside of a specified area).

I aim to identify the sample size as the percentage - i.e. the variable y - of the population that is necessary to extrapolate the movements of all subjects, fixing a error level (e.g. 5%) and a level of confidence (e.g. 90%).

Since this scenario strikes me as being different from the questionnaire/survey-kind of problem that usually goes with examples for the calculation of sample sizes and I'm not that fit in statistics, I'm not quite sure if an approach like this would yield reasonable results: http://www.raosoft.com/samplesize.html.

What do you think? Thanks for your time!

*Edit:* The ability to track the subjects doesn't depend on their time or location. We have complete information of the position of the randomly selected and tracked sample of y% of all subjects at any time, regardless of where they are.

*Edit 2:* The parameter I want to measure is the time spent on average by a subject in a subsection of the area to investigate (imagine a simple quadratic map with quadrants A1, A2, ..., B1, ...). The deviation between sample and population would be measured as difference between the actual average time spent in a quadrant and average time spent there as measured via the sample.

Comment: By error level, are you referring to standard error or prediction error?

Comment: @Silverfish The standard error.

Comment: I think you'd also need to specify whether the y% of the time that you are able to track the participants is entirely at random. If your ability to track the participants depends on the time or their location, for instance, then I suspect things get more complicated.

Comment: @Silverfish I've added that information, thanks for the hint. In short: No, it depends on neither time nor location of the subjects.

Comment: You have formulated this question to parallel the classic problem of estimating a parameter such as a population mean. The complication is that a track of a subject is far more complicated than a single numerical value is!  Could you therefore explain (a) exactly what parameter (i.e., property) of your population (of all paths of all people) you wish to estimate and (b) how you would measure deviations between estimates of that property, based on your random sample, and the true value of that property?

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your comment. Regarding (a): One could imagine the area (that the subjects are able to travel in this thought experiment) to be tiled. Assuming this, I'd ideally want to estimate how much time is spent on average in each tile. Regarding (b): One naive approach would be to measure/"penalize" the difference in time spent in each subsection. If the real average of time spent in, say, quadrant A3 is x minutes, but the average time based on my sample is y minutes, the deviation between the population and my sample would amount to x - y.